# SQL script to insert Word document Into a SQL Server 2005 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to import some Word documents into a SQL Server database. This has to be done all in SQL no C# code or little app to do it.

I have been googling how to do it but i cannot find a single example how to do it.

Lets suppose I have

1. a Word file called `MyDoc.doc`
2. A table called `Documents` with `Id=autogenerated`, `DocName varchar(255)` and `DocContent (Varbinary(Max))`

How do I insert my `MyDoc.doc` into my table using just SQL?

Many thanks

**updated**

```
DECLARE @BinarySample IMAGE
SET @BinarySample=(SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\mydoc.docx', SINGLE_BLOB)  blob)

SELECT @BinarySample


 EXEC [dbo].MyStoredProc @BinaryColumn =@BinarySample
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.sqlteam.com/article/exporting-data-programatically-with-bcp-and-xp_cmdshell

Comment: `IMAGE` is deprecated - use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead

Comment: Also: can you show us what **signature** that stored procedure has? What parameters does it expect?

Comment: @marc_s yes image is deprecated but that db.SP is not under my control.I cannot change it. the sp has 6-7 params all varchars with 1 being an image  (@docContent image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Documents(DocName, DocContent)
   SELECT
       'C:\tmp\mydoc.doc', 
       BulkColumn
   FROM
       OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\tmp\mydoc.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) blob
```

Comment: thanks a lot .Cannot believe I could not find anything on google,was googling "Insert word doc into sql server table" .Anyway thanks that works!!

Comment: or anybody why I cannot do this (see updated question) DECLARE BinarySample IMAGE
SET BinarySample=(SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\mydoc.docx', SINGLE_BLOB) blob)

SELECT BinarySample

EXEC  [dbo].MyStoredProc
BinaryColumn =@BinarySample    (OMITTED ATSIGN AS NOT ALLOWED)