# loop folder get and insert doc file to sql db one by one

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need help. I have to insert doc files into mssql with their folder names using c#. Here are some example directories:

\gpvmsrv01\INPUT\Scan\Patent\2017\2\I AP 20170115\Formula\1.doc
\gpvmsrv01\INPUT\Scan\Patent\2016\1\I AP 20160248\Description\2_u.doc
....

\gpvmsrv01\INPUT\Scan\Patent\ is unchangeable root folder. But other folders can be looped.
And the number of files are more than thousand.

Table name: patent

```
[app_number] [int] NOT NULL,
[type] [nchar](20) NULL,
[filename] [nchar](10) NULL,
[data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
```

I should iterate through all directories.

SO my first row values

```
app_number=20170115
type=Formula
filename=1
data=1.doc file
```

My second row values

```
app_number=20160248
type=Description
filename=2_u
data=2_u.doc file
```

I would be very greatfull if someone helps me with some example codes, please.

Comment: can you provide your insert query?

Comment: insert into patent (app_number, type, filename, data)
values (foldername(20170012...), foldername(Formula...), FileName(1,2,3), DataItself)

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435222/sql-script-to-insert-word-document-into-a-sql-server-2005-table

Comment: As it is this question is a bit too broad. What exactly is the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: My trouble is I have bunch of doc files and I have to insert them into DB. If it was a single doc file I could insert it easily. Looping folders, getting their names and inserting these names with doc files is a bit complicated for me as a beginner programmer. So I need some examples how to handle this in a simple way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL script to insert Word document Into a SQL Server 2005 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435222/sql-script-to-insert-word-document-into-a-sql-server-2005-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zohar pointed out in the comments, the question is too broad as it involves multiple concerns:

1. File discovery.
2. Parsing the paths to figure out the arguments
3. Database interaction to update the target table.

I assume you don't know where to start, so I'll throw a code sample to get you started:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string baseFolder = "\\gpvmsrv01\\INPUT\\Scan\\Patent\\";
    const string query =
        "INSERT INTO Patent([app_number], [type], [filename], [data]) " +
        "VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})"
    ;

    var fileList = Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(baseFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .ToArray()
    ;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string goes here"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        foreach (var fileX in fileList)
        {
            var parts = fileX.Substring(baseFolder.Length).Split('\\');

            // extract only the number
            var appNum = Regex.Replace(parts[2], "[^0-9]", string.Empty); 
            var typ = parts[3];
            var fn = parts[4];
            var contents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileX);

            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(query, appNum, typ, fn, contents) + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Depending on the security permissions on the folders, you might want run this code as an administrator. Otherwise `UnauthorizedAccessException` is expected.

Comment: It says:
Additional information: 
var fn = parts[4];
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
What could be reason?

Comment: Yeah, most likely this code won't run at once. As I said this is a code sample, which might help you to get it started. The error you received means that there is no element at position 4 in the array. In turn, that means you've used another folder structure than you showed in your question, or probably some folder, somewhere in the tree is not formatted as expected. So you need to come up with a mechanism to recognize parameters within the path and incorporate that into the code above...